# Something is eating my SSD space

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, memory, ssd

I noticed that my 120GB SSD is almost full, but I have only 55GB data on it.

I ran Disk Analyzer and listed folders and files have around 55GB of data, and yet it says that I have only 4.4GB free memory. Also, every time I delete some data to clear some space, after few days it's almost full again even though I didn't download anything new.

I have checked the paging file and it's about 8GB (included in those 55GB from the beginning), and hibernation is disabled.

[image]

Comment: Have you run CCleaner recently?

Comment: Yes, Im running it every few days.

Comment: What programm are you unsing to scan the disk? Are you starting the tool with admin rights? Have you turned on that windows should show hidden and system files? How old is the SSD? Did you check the smart values of the SSD?

Comment: Program that I'm running is called Disk Analyzer, but I have tried 2-3 different programs and they all show the same. Yes, I am starting it with admin rights, and windows are showing hidden and system files. SSD is about 1 month old. I didn't check the smart values, how do I check them?

Comment: There are different tools to do that. Just type ssd smart tool in google and get one. May be you could also look if the disk manufactor has its own tool to check the health of the ssd. It could be the case that the ssd may have a lot of broken sectors and you cant write any data on them. The smart tool should show you if there are any issues with broken sectors.

Comment: When you say hibernation is disabled, did you run `powercfg.exe /hibernate off` from the command line?

Comment: What is Windows reporting when you open "My Computer"?

Comment: Yes,I disabled hibernation from command line. Windows report that I have 4.4GB space left.

Answer (score 0):

Try to deactivate System Restore.

If System Restore is activated you may have one or more system restore points making the folder [System Volume Information] big.

Comment: Already disabled.

Comment: I would not recomend to disable this function even if you use SSDs. You just need one broken windows update and you would wish that you had not change this setting. I know it takes space but first i would reduce the space used rather than turning this off. This just makes the live on a lot of cases a lot easier. If you disable it please consider backing up you system with some backup software.

Comment: I turns out that System Restore wasn't disabled on this disc(it was on all others) and Restore Points were taking 55GB of space. Thank you all!